# Wordpress error ssv3_payload_extractor-xxxxxxxx.php startup

Tags: wordpress, payload, extractor

I have the *ssv3_payload_extractor-GKoBgg5TR4.php startup error* listed as the first item in my error log.

It seems to be causing my site to be not accessible.  I can't login into admin, as I get: *This site can’t be reached and The connection was reset.*

I can see my sites home page OK, but other pages give me the same *This site can’t be reached and The connection was reset* message.

The next lines in the error log include:

PHP Warning:  strpos(): Empty needle in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 649
This appears multiple times, 20+ over a 2 second period according to the time stamps.

and

PHP Warning:  include_once(../wp-content/plugins/child-theme-configurator/child-theme-configurator.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /../wp-settings.php on line 303

PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening ../wp-content/plugins/child-theme-configurator/child-theme-configurator.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php70/lib/php') in /../wp-settings.php on line 303

I did review 4 themes yesterday, and appear to have lost access to the site following those live previews.

Any idea what to do to fix this?